# Why does my mouse's USB dongle prevents the WIFI card from being recognized

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04, usb, troubleshooting

I recently bought a  [Bluetooth mouse](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B08XLZ246X/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1), and stumbled up upon a really annoying problem. After using the mouse for a few hours, I rebooted my ubuntu (`uname -r` gives `5.11.0-37-generic`) and my [Wifi Card](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B07Z1W8Y16/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&th=1) was not recognized anymore. I checked every single stackoverflow or askubuntu links, but no solution worked for me. `lshw -C network` only showed the ethernet, and not my wireless interface. The *iwlwifi* drivers were all installed, and `lsmod | grep wifi` outputs

```
iwlwifi               372736  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              888832  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
```

I spent a few hours (more like days or so) trying to figure out whether my PCI was broken or my wifi card burnt. Then one day I saw a post (can't find the link) saying that USB and wifi can be a bit messy. I unplugged the USB dongle of my wireless mouth, shutdown the computer, turned it back up and **Voilà**.

The problem is that every time the computer is put to sleep, the wifi stops working when it awakes, and rebooting doesn't work. I have to shut it down properly, which is a bit boring.

**Edit :**
Now even without USB dongle plugged in, putting the computer to sleep make me loose both wifi and USB which is pretty strange. Will install newest drivers and update.

**Update :**
I updated the drivers as suggested, but I still have the flag error :

```
$ dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[    2.430713] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.438154] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    2.438167] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.22
[    2.438410] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 cc-a0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.469340] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    2.655579] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: base HW address: b0:7d:64:65:be:c2
[    2.702659] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0 wlp8s0: renamed from wlan0
```

However, I checked the messages after it went to sleep mode, and it shows curious output. See the following images (couldn't copy paste without my mouse).
[image: dmesg after leaving sleep mode part 1]
[image: dmesg after leaving sleep mode, no wifi or bluetooth, part 2]

If you could help me, it would be great.

Additional informations :

My [probe](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=8068b5b456), and what `lshw -C network`   now gives me :

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 16
       serial: 18:c0:4d:0a:3a:cc
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.11.0-37-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:35 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:f7604000-f7604fff memory:f7600000-f7603fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlp8s0
       version: 1a
       serial: b0:7d:64:65:be:c2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.11.0-37-generic firmware=59.601f3a66.0 cc-a0-59.ucode ip=10.188.132.140 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:24 memory:f7500000-f7503fff
```

No messages found in `dmesg | grep iwlwifi`  when wifi doesn't work, otherwise it gives the following :

```
[    2.414851] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.422110] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    2.422117] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.22
[    2.422292] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 cc-a0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.449827] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    2.635735] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: base HW address: b0:7d:64:65:be:c2
[    2.683293] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0 wlp8s0: renamed from wlan0
```

Finally, `lspci -nn -PP -v | grep Network` gives nothing (as expected) when the wifi card is not recognized, but otherwise yields the following :

```
00:01.3/02:00.2/03:07.0/08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
```

Comment: You don't need to use this Bluetooth USB dongle since your WiFi card probably also provides Bluetooth. PS make sure your WiFi card is also connected internally to USB (there should be a short USB cable shipped with the WiFi card)

Comment: @paladin Yes, that's correct it does provides me with Bluetooth, but I am curious as to why the dongle creates this behaviour!  
My WiFi card is correctly plugged to USB internally too :) 
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: ps: I connected to another computer via USB, which is why I used the dongle

Comment: Another interesting hint is the following: `[2.422110] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver` - this indicates that the used driver is maybe outdated/incompatible, try to use a newer driver. There are also many modern ACPI power modes, you may try to use some other ACPI power modes. You may adjust ACPI power modes in your UEFI/BIOS. Try to use some compatibility modes/less aggressive power saving modes. Look for ACPI power management.